# Redraw the old donut and create a new one by clicking on each color Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm new to programming, I'm sorry if the question is silly. I'm doing some graphics with [chart.js](/questions/tagged/chart.js).

I have managed to create a donut inside another with the onclick event, the problem I have is that it generates one for each click and I need it to do it only once. For each click in a different area of ​​the graphic that a donut generates one doughnut.

**For example:**

If you click on the red color that generates one red and grey doughnut.

If you click on green part to generate one green and grey and so on with all of them.

I would greatly appreciate the help.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasDoughnut').getContext('2d');
var backgroundColors = [
  '#fd3f4a',
  '#484848',
  '#705bc9',
  '#008ee5',
  '#00c9d8',
  '#5cc600',
  '#ffd939',
  '#ff8f00'

];

var newColors = ['#5cc600', '#ebe9e1'];

var newData = [48, 52];

var varData = [25, 18, 18, 18, 8, 48, 18, 12];

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',

  data: {
    datasets: [{

      backgroundColor: backgroundColors,
      data: varData
    }]
  },

  options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 70,
    rotation: Math.PI * -0.7,

    onClick: function(evt, elements) {

      var datasetIndex;
      var dataset;

      if (elements.length) {
        var index = elements[0]._index;
        datasetIndex = elements[0]._datasetIndex;

        // Reset old state
        dataset = chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex];
        dataset.backgroundColor = ['#5cc600', '#ebe9e1'];
        dataset.value = [58, 42],
          dataset.data = [58, 42]

      }
      // config. new data doughnut

      chart.config.data.datasets.push({
          backgroundColor: [
            '#5cc600',
            '#ebe9e1'
          ],
          dataPoints: [48, 52],
          data: [48, 52],
        }),
        chart.update();
    }

  },

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvasDoughnut" class="size-doughnut"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do a check before you push a new dataset to make sure you don't already have 2 datasets.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasDoughnut').getContext('2d');
var backgroundColors = [
  '#fd3f4a',
  '#484848',
  '#705bc9',
  '#008ee5',
  '#00c9d8',
  '#5cc600',
  '#ffd939',
  '#ff8f00'

];

var newColors = ['#5cc600', '#ebe9e1'];

var newData = [48, 52];

var varData = [25, 18, 18, 18, 8, 48, 18, 12];

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',

  data: {
    datasets: [{

      backgroundColor: backgroundColors,
      data: varData
    }]
  },

  options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 70,
    rotation: Math.PI * -0.7,

    onClick: function(evt, elements) {

      var datasetIndex;
      var dataset;

      if (elements.length) {
        var index = elements[0]._index;
        datasetIndex = elements[0]._datasetIndex;

        // Reset old state
        dataset = chart.data.datasets[datasetIndex];
        dataset.backgroundColor = ['#5cc600', '#ebe9e1'];
        dataset.value = [58, 42],
          dataset.data = [58, 42]

      }
      // config. new data doughnut

      // check to make sure we haven't already pushed a dataset
      if (chart.config.data.datasets.length < 2) {
        chart.config.data.datasets.push({
          backgroundColor: [
            '#5cc600',
            '#ebe9e1'
          ],
          dataPoints: [48, 52],
          data: [48, 52],
        }),
        chart.update();
      }
    } 
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvasDoughnut" class="size-doughnut"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow! It works perfectly. Thank you very much!
And i have another question ...  how do I make the graph change to red or yellow when I press in red or yellow?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with chart.js, but at a quick glance I didn't see anything in the evt or elements objects that would tell you which color you clicked.

Comment: The data changes whith on mouseover event. I have not specified where to click, because I'm not sure how to do it.